# Access caller name without READ_CONTACTS permission - android

Tags: android, permissions

I have thought about creating a temporary permission or access in some way to the incoming call create screen methods and use their values, but i have no idea how do so.

It is very important for me to not use this permission. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the security model of Android requires you to request the permission. There is no way to work around this unless you're running a custom rom on the device.